# Concatenate of string in perl

Tags: perl

i am trying to concatenate string in perl.

eg:

```
my $file = $table_name.".sql";
print $file;
```

I get output like:

```
Employee
.sql
```

(considering $table_name =Employee )

please suggest how to make sure the output comes in single lie without blanks.

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper($table_name);`

Answer (score 5):

Your $table_name variable contains a word 'Employee' as well as a new line character.
You can use chomp to remove the newline.

Add this before you concatenate your variables:

```
chomp $table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The chomp() function will remove newline character from the end of a string.
check http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/chomp_function.html